# Login fails on fresh install of Liferay

Tags: liferay-7, tomcat9

I have downloaded and unzipped a tomcat 9 bundle of Liferay ([PORTAL 7.3 CE GA6](https://www.liferay.com/downloads-community)). I have only configured it to connect to a local PostgreSQL DB and then launched it. Everything OK, but not the login - even though the user does exist in `user_` table, the login fails.

I have also tried to update the password directly in DB with:

```
update user_ set password_='<my_plain_password>', passwordencrypted=false where contactid=<user_id>;
```

**Very strange** is that if I check after update, the row looks as expected - the password is the one I set and the encryption is set to false - but after I login with the new password and then check again, the password goes again to the previous value.

**The question:** How can I login with an already existing user ?

Comment: Note that stackoverflow limits itself to programming related questions (see [help/on-topic]). I'd recommend to carry this question over to the Liferay Forums where it's on-topic. Voting to close here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial & error and some digging on internet I have figured it out: I had to stop the liferay server (the Tomcat), then make the DB update, restart the server and then login.

**So, somehow, it doesn't let you update the password while the server is running.**